# Winforms - ResizeEnd not being called on Form resize

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to run some code after my form is resized. However, the following code never runs when I resize. I'm sure it is something simple I looked over(I am brand new to C# and programming in general). Thanks.

```
    private void CalibrationForm_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are in the Form.ResizeEnd event.");
    }
```

Comment: Just creating the method isn't enough. Did you also hook the event using the Properties window on the form designer?

Comment: I didn't. Care to enlighten me on how to go about that? I knew it was something trivial.

Comment: did you register the event in the form events ?

Comment: right click on the form then chose properties

then choose the icon of events (like electric icon) .. then choose your method from the drop down beside ResizeEnd

Comment: `this.ResizeEnd += new EventHandler(CalibrationForm_ResizeEnd);`

Comment: I'm not sure the event handling wiring is the issue. The handler looks generated by the IDE. Check your designer file for the assignment of that event handler...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You seems not hooking the event, even hook it in the properties (right click form then properties and choose the event as in the picture)

[image]

or hook the event in the constructor as follows:

```
YourForm.ResizedEnd +=new EventHandler(CalibrationForm_Resize);
```

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea about even handling, and now I do.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the top result on google for winforms resize end not being called, here is another answer for my case.

Resize begin and resize end are not called from programmatic resizing, only from the user dragging the control.

In my case, I have a completely custom drawn Form with a button to handle drag resizing in the corner. Because a function is changing the sizing instead of a user, a simple fix is to manually call OnResizeBegin and End from the mouse up and down events of the resize button, then in your code you can subscribe to the resize end and begin events like normal.

```
        private void ResizeBTN_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            OnResizeBegin(e);
        }

        private void ResizeBTN_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            OnResizeEnd(e);
        }
```

[Form.ResizeEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)